# Android Emulator Storage Increase Not Recognized

Tags: android, emulation, partition

I'm running out of space on my emulator.  I increased the storage size, but the device doesn't seem to recognize it.

[image]

I've tried a few things with the adb commands like -partition-size and adjusting the config.ini file by changing the disk.dataPartition.size=1G.  I have verified that the userdata.img and the userdata-qemu.img are both 576.7MB. I really don't want to wipe the phone. Any ideas on how to show it that it has plenty of space?
Here is adb shell df on the device:

[image]

EDIT: AVD config

[image]

Comment: add a sd card option to your emulator

Comment: I have a "Studio Managed 1GB" sd card.

Comment: can you post that avd's configuration

Comment: updated with avd configuration.